# Pivot rows into column Googlesql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a data like below

```
ID  name  timeSpent_in_mins  
1   ABC   12
1   XYZ   24
```

I need something like

```
ID  ABC  XYZ
1  12   24
```

Need something similar to Pivot in googlesql/standard sql

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Thanks jarlh for format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Conditional Aggregation` :

```
select ID,
       sum(IF (name='ABC', timeSpent_in_mins, 0)) as ABC,
       sum(IF (name='XYZ', timeSpent_in_mins, 0)) as XYZ
  from tab
 group by ID
```

Comment: Barbaros Özhan,  I have more than 1k rows like this. Unlike month I can not put static columns like in pivot function. Need to do it dynamically.

Comment: well, unfortunately, I only know this way @syncdm2012

Comment: Anyway, Thanks Barbaros Özhan for your help

Comment: @syncdm2012 . . . This answers the question that you *asked* (and I think you should accept it -- even if I much prefer `case` to `if()`).  If you have a question about a dynamic pivot, then ask a new question.

Comment: before asking questions - please search first for similar/same question already asked and answered here on SO. Duplicates (and especially identical duplicates) are not welcome on SO. Also answering duplicates is a bad taste so you compromise those who answers.

Comment: Point noted @Mikhail Berlyant .Thanks for the information. I will be watchful in future.

Comment: @syncdm2012 - Thank you for listening :o)